# asignar correctamente el resultado de una consulta a una variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

buenas tardes estoy empezando a crear unos SP en sql server para una practicas escolares y me encontré con un problema al momento de asignar el resultado a una variable local, les dejo mi código y esperando me puedan ayudar

```
alter procedure sp_Nombre_Cliente (@id int)
 as
 begin 
 set nocount on
 declare @registros int
 set @registros =(select  COUNT(*) from Cliente c where c.ID_CLIENTE=@id ) //aqui siento que tengo el problema
 if @registros < 0
 print 'existe'
 else
 print 'mo existe'
 end
```

a cualquier id que le mando se va al no existe apesar de que si existe en la base espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Un count en sql server nunca regresara menor a 0, si no existe te dará un 0, si existe un registro o mas te regresara la cantidad de registros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La validación que tienes, nunca te funcionara correctamente, dado que el [COUNT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) nunca te regresa menor a 0, si un ítem no existe te regresa 0, y si encuentra registros te regresa la cantidad de registros localizados.

```sql
alter procedure sp_Nombre_Cliente (@id int)
as
begin 
    set nocount on
    declare @registros int
    set @registros =(select  COUNT(*) from Cliente c where c.ID_CLIENTE=@id ) //aqui siento que tengo el problema
    if @registros > 0
        print 'existe'
    else
        print 'mo existe'
end
```

Comment: vale muchas gracias